# Connection to SQL server databases from Mathematica

Tags: databaselink, sql

I am an SQL developer and very new to *Mathematica*. As per my requirement I need to make a connection from *Mathematica*  to my sql server database, after which my client will do some analysis with the data from the tables. I tried make a connection using `DatabaseExplorer`. After entering all the information (Server name, db, user, password), when I hit test button , I am getting a error saying `JDBC::error`. I even tried this

```
OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["Microsoft SQL Server (jTDS)", "HC1235/TEST_DB"], 
  "Username" -> "TESTUSER1", "Password" -> "Dataanalysis15"]
```

which gave the error

> JDBC::class not found

Can someone please help me here. Please ask me if you need more info about the question. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of connection for SQLServer:

```
  Needs["DatabaseLink`"]

  conn = OpenSQLConnection[
    JDBC["Microsoft SQL Server(jTDS)", "192.168.0.6"]
   ,"Username" -> "myUser"
   ,"Password" -> "myPass"
  ]
```